# Se me presenta un problema al hacer búsqueda filtrada en java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

En java al hacer la busqueda filtrada me da error la consola diciendo que

```
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE"123_%"
```

Error:

> Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement.

El método es el siguiente

```
public void BusquedaFiltrada(String texto) {
    try{
        String[] titulo={"Rif","Cedula","Nombre","Apellido","Telefono","TR","TC","Direccion"};
        String filtro=""+texto+"_%";
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE"+'"'+filtro+'"';

        System.out.println(SQL);
        modelo=new DefaultTableModel(null,titulo);
        sent=cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet R= sent.executeQuery(SQL);
        String [] fila=new String[8];      
        while(R.next()){
             fila[0]=R.getString(1);
             fila[1]=R.getString(2);
             fila[2]=R.getString(3);
             fila[3]=R.getString(4);
             fila[4]=R.getString(5);
             fila[5]=R.getString(6);
             fila[6]=R.getString(7);
             fila[7]=R.getString(8);
             modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
        datalistado.setModel(modelo);
        R.close();
        sent.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());      
    }
}
```

Ahora el método que le pasa el parámetro es este

```
private void txtfieldBuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String buscar=txtfieldBuscar.getText();
    BusquedaFiltrada(buscar);

}
```

Usé ese evento para que la búsqueda filtrada sea rápida. La base de datos es postgresql pero me da ese error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en tu query y en cómo lo ejecutas. Lo mejor es **no concatenar los parámetros en el query**, así evitas SQL Injection. Además, tu código se vuelve más limpio. Te recomiendo parametrizar el query:

```
String filtro= texto + "_%";
//el símbolo ? indica que es un parámetro
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE ?";
sent=cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
//colocando el valor del parámetro
sent.setString(1, filtro);
//executeQuery va sin parámetros
ResultSet R = sent.executeQuery();
//resto del código...
```

Comment: pero el setString no esta dentro de las funciones del Statement

Comment: Eso es raro, tu variable debería ser `PreparedStatement sent`

Comment: me sigue presentando el mismo error y eso que lo coloque asi String[] titulo={"Rif","Cedula","Nombre","Apellido","Telefono","TR","TC","Direccion"};
            String filtro= texto + "_%";
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE ?";
            System.out.println(SQL);
            modelo=new DefaultTableModel(null,titulo);
            sent=cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            sent.setString(1, filtro);
            ResultSet R = sent.executeQuery(SQL);
            String [] fila=new String[8];

Comment: aun asi me sigue dando el error SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE ?
Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement.

Comment: Encontré el problema. Actualicé el código de la respuesta. Remueve el parámetro de `executeQuery`.

Comment: lo tengo asi 'String[] titulo={"Rif","Cedula","Nombre","Apellido","Telefono","TR","TC","Direccion"};
            String filtro= texto + "_%";
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE filtro LIKE ?";
            System.out.println(SQL);
            modelo=new DefaultTableModel(null,titulo);
            sent=cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            sent.setString(1, filtro);
            ResultSet R = sent.executeQuery();
            String [] fila=new String[8]; '  me da el error   "ERROR: no existe la columna «filtro»
  Position: 29"

Comment: Ese ya es un problema en tu query. El mensaje de error es concreto: **no existe** la columna filtro. Revisa tu tabla y sus columnas. Por lo menos esta respuesta te ayuda a resolver el problema inicial.

Comment: se lo agradezco mucho, muchas gracias por el consejo o haré así de ahora en adelante ya me funciona

Comment: @SJuan76 en realidad creo que lo mejor sería cambiar el alcance del `PreparedStatement` a manera local y no como atributo de la clase. Pero no quise cubrir ese tema aquí porque es muy extenso para explicar (conexiones en un pool, cómo configurar un pool, cómo cambiar el diseño para que luzca así, etc etc). Además, la creación del `PreparedStatement` no ocupa mucho tiempo a nivel de aplicación y quien mantiene el statement pre compilado es la bd, esto se puede asegurar a través de parámetros de conexión.

Comment: Ah no, la verdad es que había leído mal el código y pensaba que el OP quería iterar sobre el `String[]` para hacer las queries (la manía de no hacer un SSCCE)... retiro el comentario.